# How do i add current and previous in Prolog? Beginner prolog

Tags: prolog

```
calcHeu([],K) :- nl.
calcHeu([X|Rest],K) :-
findMin(X,Y),write(Y),
calcHeu(Rest,Y).
```

if i pass [[1,2,3],[5,4,9],[7,8,9]] it will print 1 4 7 which is minimum of each list i want to add these value and return them. in a list or as single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Adding Y to a list everytime.

```
calcHeu([],K,List) :- nl.
calcHeu([X|Rest],K,[Y|Tail]) :-
findMin(X,Y),write(Y),
calcHeu(Rest,Y,Tail).
```

Do you really need the K variable? Doesn't seem to do much.